# How to addforce in a random direction to a rigidbody2d game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I add a force to a rigidbody2D game object and keep it moving at a fixed velocity? The game object also has a bounce material attached.

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
private float thrust = 10.0f;

void Start() {
}


void FixedUpdate() {
        rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 1) * thrust);
    }
```

This is what i got off of the Unity documentations website but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is the code I ended up going with and it appears to be functioning properly. The Vector2 direction and speeds can be adjusted depending on mass/ gravity.

```
float topSpeed = 15;
private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
private float thrust = 0.1f;
void Start()
{
    rb2D = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 1) * thrust);
}


void Update()
{
    if (rb2D.velocity.magnitude > topSpeed || rb2D.velocity.magnitude < topSpeed)
        rb2D.velocity = rb2D.velocity.normalized * topSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as written, once it works will accelerate the rigidbody infinitely. You'll want to cap the velocity at its maximum speed: http://answers.unity.com/answers/330805/view.html

```
 rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 1) * thrust * Time.deltaTime);

 if (rigidbody.velocity.magnitude > topSpeed)
     rigidbody.velocity = rigidbody.velocity.normalized * topSpeed;
```

If you want it to immediately set the velocity to the fixed value, then you can just set the velocity on every frame:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        // the cube is going to move upwards in 10 units per second
        rb2D.velocity = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
        moving = true;
        Debug.Log("jump");
    }

    if (moving)
    {
        // when the cube has moved over 1 second report it's position
        t = t + Time.deltaTime;
        if (t > 1.0f)
        {
            Debug.Log(gameObject.transform.position.y + " : " + t);
            t = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Your code doesn't show it so in case you aren't doing it yet, you'll want to make sure that `rb2D` is actually set to the Rigidbody2d on the object you want to manipulate. E.g. by doing in the start method:

```
void Start()
{
    rb2D = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```